# java error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

I know there are duplicate questions of this but I am having trouble applying those solutions to my code. From what I've read it seems the error might be from having multiple scanners? I'm still learning java so I'm not entirely sure. Error is near bottom of code.

```
outer: for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {

            String firstUsername = null;

            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pages));
            if (reader.readLine() == null) {
                System.out.println("EMPTY");
                reader.close();
                System.exit(0);
                return;
            } else {
                firstUsername = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(firstUsername);
            }

            reader.close();

            StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("" + accepted + ""), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                stream.forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String users = contentBuilder.toString();

            driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_search_edit_text")).click();
            Thread.sleep(500);

            driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_search_edit_text"))
                    .sendKeys(firstUsername);
            Thread.sleep(500);

            driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
            Thread.sleep(500);

            try {

                driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/echo_text")).click();
                Thread.sleep(500);

            } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {

            }

            t.tap(PointOption.point(345, 275)).perform(); // accounts
            Thread.sleep(500);

            try {

                By user = By.xpath("//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView[@index='0']//*[@text='"
                        + firstUsername + "']");
                driver.findElement(user).click();
                Thread.sleep(2500);

            } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {

                Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(pages);
                fileScanner.nextLine();

                FileWriter fileStream = new FileWriter(pages);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileStream);
                while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String next = fileScanner.nextLine();
                    if (next.equals("\n"))
                        out.newLine();
                    else
                        out.write(next);
                    out.newLine();
                }
                out.close();
                fileScanner.close();

                driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                t.tap(PointOption.point(970, 150)).perform(); // x
                Thread.sleep(500);

                continue outer;

            }

            String decision = "";
            Scanner keyInput = null;

            if (users.contains(firstUsername)) {
                decision = "y";
            } else {
                keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Satisfied user? y or n: ");
                decision = keyInput.nextLine();
            }

            if (decision.matches("n")) {

                keyInput.close();

                Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(pages);
                fileScanner.nextLine();

                FileWriter fileStream = new FileWriter(pages);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileStream);
                while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String next = fileScanner.nextLine();
                    if (next.equals("\n"))
                        out.newLine();
                    else
                        out.write(next);
                    out.newLine();
                }
                out.close();
                fileScanner.close();

                FileWriter usernameWriter1 = new FileWriter(declined, true);
                usernameWriter1.write(firstUsername);
                usernameWriter1.write("\r\n");
                usernameWriter1.close();

                t.tap(PointOption.point(335, 1835)).perform(); // search
                Thread.sleep(500);

                t.tap(PointOption.point(525, 130)).perform(); // search bar
                Thread.sleep(500);

                continue outer;

            } else {
                // decision = y

                FileWriter usernameWriter1 = new FileWriter(used, true);
                usernameWriter1.write(firstUsername);
                usernameWriter1.write("\r\n");
                usernameWriter1.close();

                FileWriter usernameWriter2 = new FileWriter(accepted, true);
                usernameWriter2.write(firstUsername);
                usernameWriter2.write("\r\n");
                usernameWriter2.close();

                Scanner keyInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Remove account? y or n:");
                String decision1 = keyInput1.nextLine();

                if (decision1.matches("n")) {

                    removeAccount = false;
                    keyInput1.close();

                } else {

                    removeAccount = true;
                    keyInput1.close();
                }

                if (removeAccount == true) {

                    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(pages);
                    fileScanner.nextLine();

                    FileWriter fileStream = new FileWriter(pages);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileStream);
                    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String next = fileScanner.nextLine();
                        if (next.equals("\n"))
                            out.newLine();
                        else
                            out.write(next);
                        out.newLine();
                    }
                    out.close();
                    fileScanner.close();

                }
            }

            MobileElement postCount = (MobileElement) driver
                    .findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_profile_header_textview_post_count"));
            String amtPost = postCount.getText();

            if (amtPost.matches("0")) {

                usingFollowers = true;
                driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_profile_header_textview_followers_count"))
                        .click();
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                break;

            } else {

                Scanner keyInput2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Use followers or post likers?: f or p");
                String decision2 = keyInput2.nextLine(); // ERROR HERE

                if (decision2.matches("f")) {

                    usingFollowers = true;
                    driver.findElement(
                            By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_profile_header_textview_followers_count")).click();
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                    keyInput2.close();
                    break;

                } else {
                    // none
                }
```

Ive tried

```
while(keyInput2.hasNextLine()){

    System.out.println("Use followers or post likers?: f or p");
    String decision2 = keyInput2.nextLine();
    
    if (decision2.matches("f")) {

        usingFollowers = true;
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_profile_header_textview_followers_count")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        keyInput2.close();
        break;

        } else {
            // none
        }
}
```

But all it did was skip the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was correct. I solved the problem by making only one scanner a global variable and handling all inputs through that scanner.